# target no detecta id creado desde JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, atributos

En esta ocasión les traigo un problema de javascript, específicamente con la propiedad *target*. Resulta que desde javascript creo un div llamado *div1*, al cual desde java le doy las propiedades, entre estas un id, y todo este div luego lo hago hijo de de un span creado desde html para que así se visualice. A su vez, todo esto está dentro de una función que utilizo para que al dar click en un botón creado desde html se vayan creando divs según desee el usuario y cada uno con id distinto. Ahora, se supone que al dar click al elemento creado, el div ya mencionado, este me debe devolver su id, y es aquí donde surge el problema; yo creo otra función para que esto funcione a la cual enlazo con *onclick* al span creado en html y cuando la función se ejecuta me lanza el error * Cannot read property 'id' of undefined*, y lo raro está en que si creo un *console.log()* dentro de la misma función, este me devuelve todos sus atributos incluyendo el id de este div, por lo que debería estar definido no?.

HTML

```
    <div class="principal">
    <div class="b" id="b">

      <span class="span1" id="span1" onclick="f()"  >
        </span>
 
    </div>

<input type="button" value="buscar" onclick="buscar()" class= "boton1">
 </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
let div1="";

let i=0;
function buscar(){
i=i+1;
  div1=document.createElement("div");
div1.setAttribute("style","height:10em; width:97.8%; font-size:20px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; border-radius: 10px; background-color:#283747;color:#FFF; overflow:scroll;");
   div1.setAttribute("id",("b"+i));
  span1.appendChild(div1);
//add text crated from javascript
  var h41=document.createElement("h4");
  agregar=document.getElementById("texto2").value;
  h41= document.createTextNode(agregar);
  div1.appendChild(h41);
  //store all text
return(div1);
}

function f(){
console.log(div1);
//devuelve todas las propiedades del div
 console.log(div1.target.id);
//devuelve error (Cannot read property 'id' of undefined)
 
}
```

Bueno trate de colocar solo las lineas de código que están involucradas en el problema, quizás se topen con alguna variable que parece que no esta inicializada pero es porque lo está en otra parte del código.
Nuevamente, muchísimas gracias por su increíble servicio.

Comment: probaste con div1.getAttribute('id')?

Comment: `span1` no la estás referenciando a nada.

Comment: con respecto a tu pregunta facu aquino, si, ya intente con esa opción, solo que no me sirve por que me devuelve el ultimo valor guardado y yo necesito el valor que clickee.

Comment: y con respecto la pregunta de pollo, eso fue algo raro a lo que no recibí respuesta hace mucho tiempo pero tampoco me preocupó demasiado, pues parece da igual si obtengo el valor del span1 con (getElementById) o si solo escribo (span1 ) directamente, el programa lo entiende sin necesidad de utilizar la primera opción, cosa que no sabía. De todas maneras ya intente guardarlo en una variable (let span1=document.getElementById("span1") y de todas maneras no funcionó. Supongo que a eso te refieres, espero haber entendido tu pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios errores de lógica:

- No es conveniente que asignes el evento al *span*, porque realmente lo necesitas en cada *div* creado
- Tampoco es necesario definir la variable *div1* como global, porque cada nuevo *div* se va a tratar de forma individual, entonces, la variable se define dentro de las funciones
- El evento se asigna a cada *div* creado, de forma que puedas acceder sin problema
- En la función, es necesario recibir el evento como parámetro y accedes al elemento que lo disparó con `.target`. No te funcionaba porque estabas queriendo obtener esta propiedad donde no está disponible

```js
let i=0;
function buscar(){
  i=i+1;
  let div1=document.createElement("div");
  div1.setAttribute("style","height:10em; width:97.8%; font-size:20px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; border-radius: 10px; background-color:#283747;color:#FFF; overflow:scroll;");
  div1.setAttribute("id",("b"+i));
  // Asignar evento al div
  div1.addEventListener('click', f);
  span1.appendChild(div1);
//add text crated from javascript
  var h41=document.createElement("h4");
  agregar=document.getElementById("texto2").value;
  h41= document.createTextNode(agregar);
  div1.appendChild(h41);
  // No es necesario devolver un valor
  // return(div1);
}

// Recibir evento en la función
function f(e){
  // e.target es el elemento que lanzó el evento
  let div1 = e.target;
  console.log(div1); // Devuelve todas las propiedades del div
  console.log(div1.id); // Devuelve ID del div
}
```

```html
<div class="principal">
  <div class="b" id="b">
     <span class="span1" id="span1">
     </span>
  </div>
  <input id="texto2" value="Texto para agregar">
  <input type="button" value="buscar" onclick="buscar()" class= "boton1">
</div>
```

Comment: Buenas tardes Triby, muchísimas gracias por tu solución, me funciono perfecto. Ahora tengo una duda si no es molestia; también había intentado asignando el evento (div1.setAttribute("function", onclick="f()");) al div1 directamente, pero la función nunca se activa, esto sucede porque es una propiedad del div1 pero como no esta obteniendo los atributos del div1, nunca se detecta el click?, es lo que me imagino pero no estoy 100 por 100 seguro. Nuevamente mil gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: No, el problema es que no es así como se asignan los eventos, sino `div1.addEventListener('click', f);`